# how to parse an encoded array in php while slashes exist

Tags: javascript, php, json

This is an array I need to encode with PHP `json_encode`:

```
[["url" => "uploads/123.png"] , ["url" => "uploads/456.jpg"]]
```

The result is:

```
[{"url" : "uploads//123.png"} , {"url" : "uploads//456.jpg"}]
```

I save this in HTML tag and I want to parse it with JavaScript but it returns an error.  How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `json_encode` ?

Comment: You need to escape the quotes if you embed it as a string in your javascript file.

Comment: @tkausl yes in order to save that array in HTML tag I have to encode it. json_encode()

Comment: How are you saving it into the HTML tag? Show the PHP code and the JS code that tries to parse it.

Comment: When I tested I got `\/` but I seem to remember in the past it did some weird `//`.

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 1):

For some historical reason or other that I don't remember, `json_encode` escapes `/` (either `\/` or doubles them `//`).  There is a flag to disable it `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`:

```
$json = json_encode([["url" => "uploads/123.png"], ["url" => "uploads/456.jpg"]],
                    JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Yields:

```
[{"url":"uploads/123.png"},{"url":"uploads/456.jpg"}]
```